# Timeout when connecting to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

Could anyone help debugging an EC2 connection issue? I've been struggling for many days and it drives me crazy.

The thing is like this: I've created an EC2 instance in an existing VPC and existing subnet. In the security group, I have properly set the inbound rules.
[Inboud Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYXGK.png)
SSH should be allowed. But, when I try from remote computer, I got a timeout.

```
ssh: connect to host ec2-***********.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

When I try using EC2 connect, I got the following error:

```
    There was a problem setting up the instance connection An error occurred and we were unable to connect or stay connected to your instance. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.
```

I was hoping someone could help me and suggest some other settings at the level of the subnet or the VPC? This is all new to me and I don't know what is the best approach...

Network ACL of the subnet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vBuY.png)

Thank you

Comment: What are the security groups?

Comment: check the picture. SSH port is in it. This is why I don't get it :(

Comment: Have you checked your VPC subnet associated NACL?

Comment: I have added it in the original message. As you can see, you have all traffic allowed in inbound :(

Comment: Do you access your EC2 instance from a corporate network that might block SSH traffic?
What type of AMI are you using? Have you checked if sshd enabled and started?

Comment: Try create an EC2 instance IAM role with `AmazonEC2RoleforSSM` managed policy, attach that role to your instance, then restart your instance. Then from the console connect using SSM Session Manager and make sure that everything is correct and sshd is working correctly.

Comment: I'm trying from EC2 Connect, from an amazon workspace and from remote computer. All the three case, impossible to connect...

Comment: @amsou What VPC are you using? Can you launch a second instance and confirm that it also has no internet? Is the issue specific to a single instance, or any instance launched into same vpc and subnet?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I have tried with many EC2 instances actually. Recreated many, and always same problems

Comment: Can you confirm that you are launching instance into public subnet and that the subnet is correctly configured to use internet gateway.

Comment: How can I check that the public subnet is properly configured to use internet gateway? Sorry, this has been configured by another person and I have no idea :(

Comment: @amsou Can you ask that other person how the vpc and subnet are setup?

Comment: @Marcin: unfortunately I can't. but I can update if something needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are the following basic thump rule for access via ssh

1. EC2 subnet should be in Public subnet(subnet should be connected to internet gateway)
2. NACL should allow external traffic
3. Security group should allow port 22 from remote IP(you can choose my IP in security group settings).
4. You need the same Private key which you configured while creating instances.
5. Elastic IP or public IP to ssh into the system.